# FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a FrameLayout with a ScrollView and an AdView banner at the bottom.
I think there's a way to delete the RelativeLayout that contains both the ScrollView and the AdView and to keep the UI as is now but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg"
tools:context="">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- A LOT of stuff -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="" />

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the RelativeLayout and change the FrameLayout to a LinearLayout

Comment: I'm using a tabbed UI so I need FrameLayout as root element

Comment: What do you mean by "tabbed UI"?

Comment: I'm using an Activity with Tabs

Comment: The `Activity` class doesn't have an API for tabs. So how are you creating your tabs?

Comment: I mean http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: Nothing on that link states that you are required to use `FrameLayout` as the root element. Where did you get this information?

Comment: Do you want the ad to appear at the bottom no matter which tab is selected?

Comment: Code-Apprentice you're right!! 
I was sure of having to use FrameLayout but it works perfectly with RelativeLayout! Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove either the `FrameLayout` or the `RelativeLayout`. In fact, you should consider using a `LinearLayout` as the root element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: yes so Adview is always visible...otherwise if you know the AdBar dimension just set a margin bottom for scrollView ...